# Comparison fails when converting Opportunity from/to JSON

Tags: apex, unit-test, json

I am facing an issue when converting an Opportunity to and then from JSON.
If I put that in a test, the assertion fails when comparing both Opportunities.

Here is my code:

Test case:

```
static testMethod void opportunityCanBeConvertedToJSONFormatAndBack () {

    Opportunity opportunity = Build.anOpportunity().build();
    Opportunity jsonOpportunity = Opportunities.opportunityFromJSON( Opportunities.opportunityToJSON(opportunity) );

    // all this assertions pass
    System.assertEquals(opportunity.Name, jsonOpportunity.Name);
    System.assertEquals(opportunity.StageName, jsonOpportunity.StageName);
    System.assertEquals(opportunity.AccountId, jsonOpportunity.AccountId);
    System.assertEquals(opportunity.Amount, jsonOpportunity.Amount);
    System.assertEquals(opportunity.Sale_Steps__c, jsonOpportunity.Sale_Steps__c);
    System.assertEquals(opportunity.CloseDate, jsonOpportunity.CloseDate);

    // this assertion fails... 
    System.assertEquals(opportunity, jsonOpportunity);
}
```

The Build class creates the opportunity as follows:

```
public Opportunity build () {
    if (account == null) {
        account = anAccount().build();
        insert account;
    }
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name = name,
                                      CloseDate = Date.today(),
                                      StageName = 'Opportunity stage name',
                                      AccountId = account.Id,
                                      Amount = this.anAmount,
                                      Sale_Steps__c = saleStep
    );

    return opp;
}
```

And finally, this is how the Opportunities class makes the JSON convertion:

```
public static String opportunityToJSON(Opportunity opp) {
    return System.Json.serialize(opp);
}

public static Opportunity opportunityFromJSON(String json) {
    return (Opportunity) System.Json.deserialize(json, Opportunity.class);
}
```

Finally, the error message shows the same string conversion for the Opportunities,

```
Assertion Failed: 
Expected: Opportunity:{Name=An opportunity, StageName=Opportunity stage name, Amount=null, AccountId=001i000000oVNChAAO, Sale_Steps__c=Prospecting, CloseDate=2014-04-22 00:00:00}, 
Actual: Opportunity:{Name=An opportunity, StageName=Opportunity stage name, Amount=null, AccountId=001i000000oVNChAAO, Sale_Steps__c=Prospecting, CloseDate=2014-04-22 00:00:00}
```

so I am guessing that it should be a deeper comparison that is failing (maybe a TZ, or something inside the Account?), but I can't figure it out, so any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!
Juan M.

**Update**

I forgot to say that using System.assert and comparing with == also fails.

Comment: You may have already seen this thread, but fyi: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008xsmIAA.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have seen that thread and all the proposed solutions involve comparing objects field by field, or using String representations. I am currently using one of this methods, but I see it as a workaround. I am trying to find out why standard comparison does not work, or why it can't be used.

Comment: Yep would be good to understand the root cause.

Comment: I suggest you go through all the fields using describe and assert each one individually. According to documentation, the == is based in comparing each field. This should point to what changes.
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm

Comment: Certainly seems like a bug, I flagged it with the apex team.

Comment: Fix is targeted for Winter '16. Safe harbor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it has been fixed in Winter 16.

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_apex_json_ids.htm

Thanks!
Juan M.

Answer (score 3):

I tried comparing each field separately using describe and it works.  But the equals for opportunity still fails. I think this is a bug.
Here's the code:

```
@isTest
class OpportunityToJsonBug {
    private static testMethod void testBug() {
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test Opp', StageName = 'Prospecting');
        String json = System.Json.serialize(opp);
        Opportunity jsonOpp = (Opportunity) System.Json.deserialize(json, Opportunity.class);
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> M = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.fields.getMap();
        for(String fieldName :  M.keySet()) {
             Object oppField  = opp.get(fieldName);
             Object jsonOppField  = jsonOpp.get(fieldName);
             System.assertEquals(oppField, jsonOppField, 'Failed when comparing field ' + fieldName);
        }

        Opportunity controlOpp = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test Opp', StageName = 'Prospecting');
        System.assertEquals(opp, controlOpp);

        // fails here...        
        System.assertEquals(opp, jsonOpp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Where is one supposed to report this?

Comment: @JuanAlvarez Open a case with Salesforce Support

Comment: Reported! I will let you know as soon as I have news. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I was able to replicated this for all Fields on an Account and got same error.

Comment: Opportunity a = new Opportunity(name='test1');
Account a1 = new Account(name = 'woop');
Account a2 = new Account(name = 'woop');
Account a3 = (Account)JSON.deserialize('{"name" : "woop"}', Account.class);
Account a4 = (Account)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(a1), Account.class);
 
System.debug( a1 == a2 ); // true
System.debug( a1 === a2); // false
System.debug( a3 == a1 ); // true
System.debug( a4 == a1 ); // false but should be true

Comment: String[] types = new String[]{'Account'};
Schema.DescribeSobjectResult[] results = Schema.describeSObjects(types);
System.debug('Got describe information for ' + results.size() + ' sObjects.');
for(Schema.DescribeSobjectResult res : results) {
System.debug('Number of fields: ' + res.fields.getMap().size());
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mfields = res.fields.getMap();
for(Schema.SObjectField field : mfields.values())
{     
    if(a1.get(field.getDescribe().getName()) != a3.get(field.getDescribe().getName()))
       {System.debug('NOT EQUAL!!!!');}
}
}

Comment: @Superfall has this code for the Account JSON, I just did Schema Describe like you did. All Fields are ++. Strange Bug!